# Is it possible to display WPF UI components in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp

I have a huge application in `WPF` and step by step I move the UI to `UWP` (using `XamlIslands`).

In a list view for the items I have a very complex item template (still in WPF), and I'd like to create the `ListView` itself in UWP (because of the smooth scrolling) and to display the items from the WPF item template. Is it possible to inject somehow the WPF UI into a UWP list item?

*More background:*

- The scrolling in a WPF `ListView` by default is very jittery (I mean it's not smooth as it is in a UWP ListView). A ListView item could cover the whole screen (it also contains a web view), so this is not acceptable from UX point of view
- Yes, there is a way to make it smooth in WPF, but then I loose the virtualization. But this is very important, because I could have many items in that list.

I appreciate any other idea as well.

Comment: You want to provide some code that reproduce the behavior. WPF is very fast (60fps) when properly discharged from heavy functions to the background with `Task.Run`, whithout which every thing is executed in the UI thread. I see here a XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.
Eventually you can go further than the xaml islands and  have several processes in one window (actually several) when you inject a window in a WPF host control (and likely a UWP host control).

Comment: Furthermore, can you develop "there is a way to make it smooth in WPF, but then I loose the virtualization" ?

Comment: At last, you can profile your app in VS2019 with alt+F2 to see where/when is it slow and what is the root cause (which functions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to inject somehow the WPF UI into a UWP list item?

Short answer: No.

You can use XAML islands to inject UWP components into your WPF application but it doesn't work the other way around, i.e. you cannot inject WPF components into your UWP app.